# Neomutt Pipe Attachments to Shell Program from Menu

Tags: shell, email, mutt

The header of the attachments menu in neomutt gives the options

> q:Exit  s:Save  |:Pipe  p:Print  ?:Help

I assumed that the Pipe option would allow me to pipe a chosen attachment to the shell. In particular, maybe I want to open a file in a way that bypasses the mailcap defaults.

Suppose I wanted to open a file from the attachment menu with `open`. Is there a way to achieve this with  `Pipe` and not by going to edit my mailcap?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

The only downfall of this is you need to specify all types, because wildcard can be only in subtype - `*/*` or `*` doesn't work

Store original mailcap file location in a variable

Define macro in attach menu that changes mailcap file to a new one, run view-attach (which uses `open` to open a file with) and return to original mailcap_path configuration.

~/.muttrc

```
set my_origmailcap=$mailcap_path

macro attach <Space> "\
<enter-command>set mailcap_path=~/.mailcap2<enter>\
<view-attach>\
<enter-command>set mailcap_path=$my_origmailcap<enter>\
"
```

~/.mailcap2

```
audio/* ; open %s
image/* ; open %s
text/*  ; open %s
video/* ; open %s
```